# Teradata - An illegally formed character string was encountered during translation

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, teradata, twitterapi-python

I am fetching tweets via Twitter API in pandas dataframe and writing the data to teradata database. However, unlike other tweets one cell has specific tweet which contains data in bold. When I try to insert it in database, it pops up the following error:

```
OperationalError: [Version 17.0.0.4] [Session 3046127] [Teradata SQL Driver] [Error 528] A failure occurred while executing rows 1 through 292 of a batch request.
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).makeDriverErrorCode TeradataConnection.go:1120
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.newTeradataRows TeradataRows.go:396
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataStatement).QueryContext TeradataStatement.go:122
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).QueryContext TeradataConnection.go:2083
 at database/sql.ctxDriverQuery ctxutil.go:48
 at database/sql.(*DB).queryDC.func1 sql.go:1579
 at database/sql.withLock sql.go:3204
 at database/sql.(*DB).queryDC sql.go:1574
 at database/sql.(*Conn).QueryContext sql.go:1823
 at main.goCreateRows goside.go:654
 at main._cgoexpwrap_cfa80c8a3acb_goCreateRows _cgo_gotypes.go:363
 at runtime.cgocallbackg1 cgocall.go:332
 at runtime.cgocallbackg cgocall.go:207
 at runtime.cgocallback_gofunc asm_amd64.s:793
 at runtime.goexit asm_amd64.s:1373
Caused by [Version 17.0.0.4] [Session 3046127] [Teradata Database] [Error 6705] An illegally formed character string was encountered during translation.
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).formatDatabaseError TeradataConnection.go:1138
 at gosqldriver/teradatasql.(*teradataConnection).makeChainedDatabaseError TeradataConnection.go:1154
```

The tweets datatype in database is "varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET UNICODE NOT CASESPECIFIC"

Here is the sample data:

[image]

The tweet containing bold text is causing the problem in insertion. How do I mitigate this?

Comment: Hard to be certain without knowing the actual code points in the input, but perhaps execute `SET SESSION CHARACTER SET UNICODE PASS THROUGH ON;` prior to loading. That allows arbitrary characters outside the Teradata "server Unicode" repertoire.

Comment: @Fred - won't you eventually still have to handle the multi-byte characters?  Or am I over-thinking this.

Comment: @Andrew - Depends on how you are going to use the data. You could use Unicode Pass Through for querying, if you want to simply retrieve the original values.

Comment: Otherwise you may want to "normalize" the Unicode text using `unicodedata.normalize`  in Python before loading or `TRANSLATE` in the database after loading.

Comment: Note also that normalization might be sufficient for "letter-like" characters as in the example given, but emoji (for instance) would still require UPT.

Comment: @Fred, I executed SET SESSION CHARACTER SET UNICODE PASS THROUGH ON; before inserting the data and it worked. Please write it as an answer so that I could accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store or retrieve arbitrary Unicode code points, use the Unicode Pass-Through feature both for loading and querying sessions.

```
SET SESSION CHARACTER SET UNICODE PASS THROUGH ON;
```

For the specific example given, you might find it useful to "normalize" the Unicode text, e.g. with Python `unicodedata.normalize` before loading or Teradata `TRANSLATE(...)` after loading if you wanted the corresponding ASCII letter characters - but that would not apply for other Unicode characters such as emoji that may also occur in the input.